# How to return exact error from the python script through flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am calling python function to call a script to create a directory.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

 

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def share_drive():

    try:
    
        parentdir = request.json.get("parentdir")

        dirname = request.json.get("dirname")

        #parentdir = request.values.get("parentdir")

        #dirname = request.values.get("dirname")

                path = os.path.join(parentdir, dirname)

    # makedirs create directory recursively

    try:
    
        os.makedirs(path)

        #return ("Success Fileshare created: {} ".format(dirname))
        resp = make_resopnse('{} successfully created.'.format(dirname))
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    
    except OSError as error:
    
        #return ("Fileshare creation failed: {} ".format(dirname))       
        resp = make_resopnse('Failed to create fileshare {}'.format(dirname))
        resp.status_code = 400
        return resp
```

I am calling it through post man, return statements are working. But I am making response from return and passing resp.status code and that part is failing.

Error in post man

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: The code is not complete. At least the second except statement or finally statement is missing. It is possible that no OSError was raised but a different one, or as GAEfan suggest, another exception is raised in your except block.

Comment: If nothing helps, I recommend to use a debugger - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    os.makedirs(path)

    #return ("Success Fileshare created: {} ".format(dirname))
    resp = Response('{} successfully created.'.format(dirname))
    print (resp)
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp

except OSError as error:

    #print(error)
    resp = Response('{} fileshare creation failed.{} filename  already exists'.format(dirname, error))
    print (resp)
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp 
    #return ("Fileshare creation failed: {} ".format(dirname))
```

This has  fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are typos in your `except`:

```
return ("Fileshare creation failed: {} ". formart(dirname))
```

should be:

```
return ("Fileshare creation failed: {} ".format(dirname))
```

and, in case `dirname` is not defined (it should be always, but good coding form to show the exact error):

```
print(error)
return ("Fileshare creation failed: {} ".format(dirname))
```